# use vue component in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

Hello I need a help with generating multiple vue component (vue-popperjs - for tooltip).

In code bellow, components appear on page but I cant to interact with them(button wont toggle tooltip and tooltip is show by default) and I have a error in console 
"vue.common.js?e881:560 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: 
(found in )"

and

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at VueComponent.mounted (eval at  (app.js:909), :117:64)
    at callHook (eval at  (app.js:891), :2275:21)
    at Object.insert (eval at  (app.js:891), :2954:7)
    at invokeInsertHook (eval at  (app.js:891), :4960:28)
    at Vue$3.patch [as __patch__] (eval at  (app.js:891), :5124:5)
    at Vue$3.Vue._update (eval at  (app.js:891), :2042:19)
    at Vue$3.updateComponent (eval at  (app.js:891), :2158:10)
    at Watcher.get (eval at  (app.js:891), :2469:25)
    at Watcher.run (eval at  (app.js:891), :2539:22)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (eval at  (app.js:891), :2331:13)
```

Code:

```
<span class="input" v-for="additionalCategory in additionalCategories">
  <p>@{{ additionalCategory.name }}

    <popper trigger="click" :options="{placement: 'right'}" :content="additionalCategory.tooltip_text">
      <div class="additionalCategory.tooltip_text">
        @{{ additionalCategory.tooltip_text }}
      </div>

      <button slot="reference">
        Reference Element
      </button>
    </popper>
    <span v-if="additionalCategory.tooltip_active" class="tooltip-div" @click="showTooltip(additionalCategory.tooltip_text, additionalCategory.id, $event)">

      <span class="tooltip_toggle" v-bind:class="additionalCategory.id"></span>
    </span>
  </p>

  <div class="input-action">
    <div class="counter">
      <input type="text" :value="additionalCategory.quantity" :id="additionalCategory.id">

      <div class="ico"><img :src="'/images/icons/'+additionalCategory.icon+'.png'"
                            :id="additionalCategory.name"></div>
      <div class="plus-minus">
        <div class="minus" v-on:click="clickMinus($event, additionalCategory.id)"></div>
        <div class="plus" v-on:click="clickPlus($event, additionalCategory.id)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

I was register popper in app.js:

```
Vue.component('popper', require('vue-popperjs'));
```

and as same component work but not in for loop.
Please help me, I don't have idea what to do.

Comment: What is the javascript code for *your* component?

Comment: That's plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-popperjs

Comment: I understand. I mean your code. Not the template.

Comment: I don't understand you what code? Do you mean on additionalCategorie?
I was just implement that plugin and use him, I don't have my js code for that.

Comment: Yes, where is `additionalCategories` defined? Where is `new Vue(...)`, etc.

Comment: It's on bottom of the page. I have a ~500 lines of code.
data {
additionalCategories: {},
}
I'm sending additonalCategories from backend and JSON.parse on that and I have objects. Do you want to shot ss from console and post?

Comment: So... put it in a pastebin/gist?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UKd0guKN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147847/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-duka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here came down to the `popper` component being embedded in a paragraph element (`<p></p>`). Taking it out of that element solved the issue.